# ajax in rails: remote: true on a specific form field not submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I know that you can submit a form in rails via an ajax request by simply supplying `remote: true`:

```
<%= form_for(@user, remote: true) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Now: when the form submits: instead of an HTTP request it is an ajax request.

What I want to do is submit a JS request (ajax request) *not for the entire form*, but for a specific field element, but it is not working. Specifically: the ajax request should fire off when the user makes a selection within the select box:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :food_type_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :food_type_id, FoodType.all, :id, :name, remote: true %>        
  </div>

  ...

<% end %>
```

I would expect an AJAX request to be sent to the server since I provided the `remote: true` option on the field.  So: whenever the user makes a selection: an ajax request fires off.  However: nothing is happening.

What am I missing? I know that I could do it all myself: bind an event listener to the select box on the client side and fire off a request when the select box changes.  However: I thought `remote: true` can handle ajax requests for you, so there would be no need for me to do any custom-ajax-request building.

Comment: What does js console says when you try to submit the select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails' built-in form helpers allow you to use `remote: true` on the following helpers: `form_tag`, `form_for`, `link_to`, and `button_to`. Adding `remote: true` to a single field inside the form will have no effect. See [Working with Javascript in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers).

You will need to bind a javascript function to the `food_type_id` select:

```
$('select#user_food_type_id').change(function() {
  $.ajax({
     url: '/food_types.json', // you could be fancy and set this in a data attribute.
     success: function(response) {
       // update your form with the response from your ajax request
     }
  });
});
```